# SecurityIntelliSense Warning: Explicit usage of accesstoken found in the code

Tags: security, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, warnings, access-token

I got a securityIntelliSense warning:

> Explicit usage of accesstoken found in the code: access tokens should
>   be handled securely. It is recommended not to store it separately in a
>   persistent storage like databases or files, unless there is a
>   compelling requirement.

The code looks like this:

```
  public string GetAccessToken()
        {
            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Concat(_aadInstance, _tenantId));
            var credential = new ClientCredential(_clientId, _clientSecret);
            var authResult = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(_appResourceId, credential).Result;
            return authResult.AccessToken;
        }
```

The warning happens in the last line: `authResult.AccessToken`

I was wondering if there's any way to fix the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if there's any way to fix the warning?

It seems that you enabled the [Security IntelliSense - Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AzSDKTeam.SecurityIntelliSense-Preview)  tool.

But It just a warning information to give some tips to handle the security access token. 
If you still don't want to show that waring information. You could **disable**  or **uninstall** the extension.

We could find it under Tool->Extensions and Updates

[image]